# Nodejs - read line by line from file, perform async action for each line and resume

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a file line by line, perform some action that has a callback and when the function finishes to resume line reading. For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');
var instream = fs.createReadStream('./phrases.txt');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
rl.on('line', function (line) {
  rl.pause();
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('resuming');
    rl.resume();
  }, 2000);
});
```

I was under the impression the example above should basically read a line, wait for 2 seconds, `console.log` and then continue to the next line. What really happens is that it waits for the first 2 seconds and then spews out lots of `console.log`

Comment: This is because `rl.on` fires very rapidly in succession. It is asynchronous, so one `rl.on` doesn't wait for the previous one to complete. It fires whenever the next line has been read, which should be pretty fast.  So if `rl.on` fires one millisecond after another, your time out function merely starts in parallel one millisecond after another. So if if you have 10 lines in the file, the total delay is 2.000010s, and not 20s!

Comment: Hi! Please, can you mark my answer as valid if it works for you? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 21):

[Line by Line](https://github.com/Osterjour/line-by-line) module helps you reading large text files, line by line, without buffering the files into memory.

You can process the lines asynchronously. This is the example provided:

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
    lr = new LineByLineReader('big_file.txt');

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // pause emitting of lines...
    lr.pause();

    // ...do your asynchronous line processing..
    setTimeout(function () {

        // ...and continue emitting lines.
        lr.resume();
    }, 100);
});

lr.on('end', function () {
    // All lines are read, file is closed now.
});
```

Comment: This is actually synchronous. Because each line will be processed only until the last line has been processed?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It solves exactly what the question asks. After several hours of trying to figure this out on my own, this is the solution I ended up using.

Comment: This is the real answer. Other modules just pretend to be async.You really need something like pause stream.

Comment: This solution uses events, which are hard to scale and have become less popular over the years. Another solution below uses `line-reader`, which uses a callback, for processing, and promises, for wrap up.

Answer (score 16):

Solution **without installing** any external library. You only need the native node.js "readline" module. Just do the following:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import readline from "readline";

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.txt'))
});

for await (const line of readInterface){
  await someAsynchronousOperation();
}
```

Source (Official documentation): https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator

Answer (score 5):

A very nice line-reader module exists, 
https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader

simple code:

```
 var lineReader = require('line-reader');
   lineReader.eachLine('file.txt', function(line, last) {
      // do whatever you want with line...
      console.log(line);
      if(last){
         // or check if it's the last one
      }
   });
```

also "java-style" interface for more control:

```
lineReader.open('file.txt', function(reader) {
  if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    reader.nextLine(function(line) {
      console.log(line);
    });
  }
});
```

Another cool solution:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    sleep = require('sleep'),
    readline = require('readline');

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('phrases.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log('-------')
    console.log(line);
    sleep.sleep(2)

});
```

Comment: I think it was added keeping the OP's requirement in mind, I thought he is trying to read a line and then wait and then read a line and so on..

Answer (score 2):

```
function createLineReader(fileName){
    var EM = require("events").EventEmitter
    var ev = new EM()
    var stream = require("fs").createReadStream(fileName)
    var remainder = null;
    stream.on("data",function(data){
        if(remainder != null){//append newly received data chunk
            var tmp = new Buffer(remainder.length+data.length)
            remainder.copy(tmp)
            data.copy(tmp,remainder.length)
            data = tmp;
        }
        var start = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] == 10){ //\n new line
                var line = data.slice(start,i)
                ev.emit("line", line)
                start = i+1;
            }
        }
        if(start<data.length){
            remainder = data.slice(start);
        }else{
            remainder = null;
        }
    })

    stream.on("end",function(){
        if(null!=remainder) ev.emit("line",remainder)
    })

    return ev
}


//---------main---------------
fileName = process.argv[2]

lineReader = createLineReader(fileName)
lineReader.on("line",function(line){
    console.log(line.toString())
    //console.log("++++++++++++++++++++")
})
```

Comment: You're basically rewrote the `readline` built-in module without solving OP's issue, where your `lineReader`'s line event will fire off without waiting for async events

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution in typescript using line-reader that can run in nodejs 8:

```
import lineReader from 'line-reader';

function readLines(filename: string, processLine: (line: string) => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lineReader.eachLine(filename, (line, last, callback) => {
      if (!callback) throw new Error('panic');
      processLine(line)
        .then(() => last ? resolve() : callback())
        .catch(reject);
    });
  });
}

async function echo(): Promise<void> {
  await readLines('/dev/stdin', async (line) => {
    console.log(line);
  });
}

echo();
```

Note that it does not buffer the whole file before executing, therefore it is suitable for processing large text files.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [`stdio`](https://github.com/sgmonda/stdio) for this kind of things, as input stream is paused and resumed automatically and you don't need to worry about your system resources. You'll be able to read really huge files with just a few MBs of memory:

This example prints a line every 2 seconds:

```
$ node myprogram.js < file.txt
```

```js
import { read } from 'stdio';

async function onLine (line) {
  console.log(line);
  await sleep(2000);
}

read(onLine)
  .then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

Note I'm using an asynchronous `sleep` to represent any asynchronous task. It is not included in Node.js by default but it would be as follows:

```js
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('sample.txt')
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
});
```

source: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line

Comment: Although your code is cleaner, it is functionally no different than the code in the question. Adding a setTimeout does exactly the same in your code. I too have been looking for a solution to my problem for the past couple hours. There doesn't seem to be any good native (inbuilt nodejs) way to accomplish running tasks before continuing onto the next line.

Comment: This doesn't do what he's asking: `I'm trying to read a file line by line, perform some action that has a callback *and when the function finishes to resume line reading*`